# Confused about ui-router nesting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to find a way for one of my views to have multiple states. Let's say I have this template:

```
<body>
  <div ui-view="overlay">
  <div ui-view="content">
</body>
```

...and these routes:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('base', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
     views: {
      'overlay': {
        templateUrl: '/src/overlay.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('base.page1', {
    url: '/page1/',
    views: {
      'content@': {
        templateUrl: '/src/page1.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('base.page2', {
    url: '/page2/',
    views: {
      'content@': {
        templateUrl: '/src/page2.html',
      }
    }
  });
```

This allows me to show the "overlay" view on page1 and page2.

The "overlay" view needs to be able to change its state without affecting anything else on the page. I can set up "overlay" as a parent state and add children to it, but I can't figure out a way to activate any of those `overlay.child` states from inside a `base` state without losing whatever was in the `base` state. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

edit: plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/vPmNhVLZNI2fOAZZOHkg

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but maybe what you want is to make them nested?

```
<div ui-view="parent">
    <div ui-view="child">

    </div>
</div>


$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        url: "/",
        views: {
            'parent': {
               templateUrl: '/view/parent.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('parent.child', {
        url: "/",
        views: {
            'child@parent': {
               templateUrl: '/view/child.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

Or is this not what you are looking for?

### Edit:

What about [this solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQ0cHghFcJS0y7k0nGXb?p=preview)

And if you want you can use variables for your current state so that you don't have to define the overlay states for all parent states in your routeProvider like shown in [this dirty example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQ0cHghFcJS0y7k0nGXb):

### Edit2:

What you actually want is parallel states. You can read [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/475) on the topic and then you find out it is not yet supported in ui-router. But as written in my comment below you can take a look at `ng-switch` if you don't really need the state variables, since you can create similar parallel behavior with that directive.

Comment: I'm not sure it would solve my problem - in addition to changing the child state (to render different pages) I need a separate state hierarchy within the overlay, with both hierarchies working independently. Hopefully my plunker might clarify things, but I'm getting the impression this isn't what ui-router was designed for

Comment: Check my edit in the plunker. Now the base state is hard-coded but you can of course also use current state variables to make sure you link the correct base state...

Comment: I see, thanks. But wouldn't this mean I'd need to duplicate the overlay states as children of each base state?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use a variable in your routeProvider for the current base state. Then use this variable in the route definition. Like this: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQ0cHghFcJS0y7k0nGXb)

Comment: How do you actually trigger the overlay change. On user interaction?

Comment: Yeah, always from within links inside the overlay.

Comment: Then I think this solution will be at least the right direction for you. The overlay should be a child so it doesn't change the parent state and you can use a variable for current parent state.

Comment: Cheers, although I'm not too sure about the variable on the app.js level... I think with your example it'd be impossible to change it from inside the app, so I'd need to use $rootScope and access that from inside the config function (which is still pretty rough). I'll definitely keep it in mind as an option but I'll have a look at alternatives for now.

Comment: That is of course a very very dirty solution just to show you that it is possible. You should never do it like that in your real project of course :) You can also look into the `ui-router` documentation if they have some native solutions available

Comment: I gave it another thought. What you actually want is parallel state handling. There is a post [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/475) on the topic. I also wondered do you really need states for your parallel views. Otherwise I would suggest to also take a look at `ng-switch`. It might be another solution with same result.

Comment: Yes, that would solve my problem perfectly! I think you are right with using ng-switch. The overlay definitely has distinct states but instead of using ui-router I'll just create a service with a state variable. This should be enough for now, but it's good to know the parallel stuff is being considered. Thanks again Wilt!